# Ajax to submit form generated dynamically by PHP do-while loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have an evaluation bar(progress bar generated by javascript), users can select a value and click to submit it. The issue is that I'm using PHP to generate the evaluation bars dynamically (using a do-while loop).
I can't figure out how to setup AJAX to recognized and submit any of the forms. Now it's submitting only the first one, even though I submit any of others.

My PHP code:

```
$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form3")) { 
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO tblpersonalidad (idUser, idPost, intEvaluacion, dateFecha) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['idUser'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['idPost'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['intEvaluacion'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['dateFecha'], "timestamp"),
                   );

mysql_select_db($database_conexionproject_poll, $conexionproject_poll);
$Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $conexionproject_poll) or die(mysql_error());

$insertGoTo = "";
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
$insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
}
header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}

 do {
 <form id="form3" name="form3">

      <div class="progress-user">
           <div class="progress-bar-user progress-bar-danger-user"></div>
           <div class="progress-bar-user progress-bar-warning-user"></div>
           <div class="progress-bar-user progress-bar-success-user"><span class="rating">0%</span></div>
     </div>

      <input class="mi-input" name="intEvaluacion" type="hidden" value="" />
      <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form3" />                       
      <input type="hidden" name="intActivo" value="1" />
      <input type="hidden" name="idPost" value="<?php echo $row_Datos_polls['idPost']; ?>" />
      <input type="hidden" name="idUser" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['MM_IdUser']; ?>" />
  </form>

    } while ($row_Datos_polls = mysql_fetch_assoc($Datos_polls));


<script>

$('.progress-user').on('mousemove', function (e) {
var self = this;  
var offset = $(self).offset(); 
var width = $(self).width();
var relX = Math.round(10 * (e.pageX - offset.left)/width) * 10;
setBarRating(self, relX);
$(self).siblings('.mi-input').val(relX);
});

$("#form3").submit(function(a) {
var url = "<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>"; // the script where you handle the form input.

$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: $('#form3').serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
       success: function(data)
       {
           alert(data); // show response from the php script.
       }
     });

e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
        });

$('.progress-user').click(function() {
$("#form3").submit();
});


var setBarRating = function (self, percentage) {
$(self).find('.progress-bar-success-user span.rating').text(percentage + '%'); 
if (percentage <= 50) {
$(self).find('.progress-bar-danger-user').width(percentage + '%');
$(self).find('.progress-bar-warning-user').width(0);
$(self).find('.progress-bar-success-user').width(0);
} else if (percentage > 50 && percentage <= 80) {
$(self).find('.progress-bar-danger-user').width('50%');
$(self).find('.progress-bar-warning-user').width((percentage - 50) + '%');
$(self).find('.progress-bar-success-user').width(0);
} else if (percentage > 80) {
$(self).find('.progress-bar-danger-user').width('50%');
$(self).find('.progress-bar-warning-user').width('30%');
$(self).find('.progress-bar-success-user').width((percentage - 80) + '%');
}
};
</script>
```

I'll really appreciate any help. I haven't could realized what is the modification to the AJAX + PHP code. Many thanks for your time.

Comment: Do you have any form other than `form3` in your code ?

Comment: This page is calling itself with Ajax? That's usually (basically always) not a good idea.

Comment: Yes, I have other forms. These ones are not in a loop and I'm submitting without AJAX.

Comment: @malmonacid001, you should have mentioned my  name after a `@` sign so that ,  I would be notified of the comment made towards me.

Comment: @malmonacid001. `Yes, I have other forms.` - where are those in your code ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed thanks for the tip. The other forms are before the code that I posted. They are working independently. But actually I'm not using them now. I've already commented them in the code.

Comment: @malmonacid001, if they are not in the code pasted in OP, how to find the solution ?

Comment: @developerwjk The idea is do not reload the page after the evaluation. So the user can keep interacting at the same point in the page and see their evaluation at the same time.

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed the other forms are not part of this issue. As I mencionated I've already took out from the code coz I'm not using any more

Comment: @malmonacid001, `Now it's submitting only the first one, even though I submit any of others.`

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed get it! ...........that means now it's submitting the first record in the do-while loop. Every record has associate a form, the same form with the record values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re generating several forms with id=”form3”. You’re also listening to $(“form3”).submit(). You’re submitting those forms by listening clicks to ‘.progress-user’:

```
$('.progress-user').click(function() { $("#form3").submit(); });
```

So, not matter wich .progress-user do you click on, the first #form3 will be the form submitted.

You should generate unique id’s to your forms and bars when creating them inside the loop. I.E;

```
$i = 0;
do {
<form id="<?php echo 'form' . $i ?>"  name="<?php echo 'form' . $i ?>"    class="progress-form">

  <div class="progress-user" id="<?php 'progress-user' . $i; ?>" data-numer="<?php echo $i; ?>"  >
       <div class="progress-bar-user progress-bar-danger-user"></div>
       <div class="progress-bar-user progress-bar-warning-user"></div>
       <div class="progress-bar-user progress-bar-success-user"><span class="rating">0%</span></div>
 </div>

  <input class="mi-input" name="intEvaluacion" type="hidden" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form3" />                       
  <input type="hidden" name="intActivo" value="1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="idPost" value="<?php echo $row_Datos_polls['idPost']; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="idUser" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['MM_IdUser']; ?>" />
  </form>
  $i++; //dont forget this :-)
} while ($row_Datos_polls = mysql_fetch_assoc($Datos_polls));
```

Now you have several forms with its own unique id and several progress bars with its unique id and a data-number attribute. Also, the dinamically generated form have that 'progress-form' class.

So now you can listen to clicks on progress bars like before, then caching the data-number of that element: 

    `$('.progress-user').click(function() { 
        var formNumber = $(this).attr('data-number');
        $("#form" + fromNumber).submit(); 
    });`

This way, you can be sure the form being submitted is the one whose progress-bar was clicked. Now you should also modify your submit listener:

```
$('.progress-form').submit(function(e){
    var url = "<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>"; 
    var data = $(this).serialize(); 

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: data,
       success: function(data)
       {
           alert(data); // show response from the php script.
       }
     });
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

So now you're serializing and sending only the form whose progress bar was clicked, and not the first '#form3' in the document.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You right.It was an additional issue. Thanks for realize that. Still the main issue how to submit any value record using a form generated dynamically as the recordset that I'm using as inputs.

Comment: So, if I understand ur code well, you're generating several forms -one foreach $datos_polls- with an id="form-3"? Independently from the issue, that's a bad practice, id's must be unique. Still, I don't understand well what you want to achieve. It's not clear if the problem is related to your program not actually updating the records, or it is related to the bars updating after ajax interactions. You should be more explicitly clear, Im afraid.

Comment: Ok, first of all, many thanks for your interest to help. I wanna submit (store) the values (idPost, idUser, etc.) associated to any of the records of $Datos_polls + intEvaluacion that select the user for that record. Due to I'm generating idPost, idUser ... using a do-while loop, the form associated to send the info must be generated of the same way. I don't know how to adapt the Ajax code part to work on that way. Assigning the respective values to the form to submit it properly. I do understand that form must have an unique id (var form = form.id; or something like that) but what else?. Thxs

Comment: I edited my answer. Now I think I solved the issue. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working fine. How we say in Chilean-spanish "Who knows .... knows" (In spanish sounds better). It means you know what are you talking about. I guess the misspellings in the code (fromNumber and data-numer) were deliberately as a test if I am attentive :-). Many thanks again. Big greetings from Santiago-Chile.

Comment: De nada! Acepta la respuesta por favor. Estuve hace años en Santiago y me pareció espectacular. Un saludo!